# JQuery UI vertical resizing and reverse resizing of multiple divs within container

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, resize, resizable

I am working on a jQuery UI tool that uses the custom alsoResizeRerverse function documented here: 
[jQuery UI Resizable alsoResize reverse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3369045/jquery-ui-resizable-alsoresize-reverse)

However my problem is more complex in that I need multiple divs within a container to reverse resize when one control element is resized.

The control elements start out as different heights of the container and thus the reverse resized elements cannot be resized equally.

For example element 1 starts out as 10%, and is resized to 50%.
Element 2 and 3 therefore start out with combined value of 90% and must total to 50% on finish.
But Element 2 and 3 have initial values of 25% and 65%, meaning that they cannot resize by the delta value of element 1 divided by 2.

Furthermore, within these 3 parent elements are multiple child elements that also must resize and reverse resize within their parents.

The elements' purpose is to allow user to set percentage value for different categories which are then used to display a graph.

Comment: No one offered a solution, I created my own in the end. Will post when I have a moment. Are you working on something similar?

Comment: yes i am working on similar thing.
I have 5 div representing 100% value 20% each. When i re-size a div the upper div should also re-size accordingly to contain a total of 100%. 
i.e when i increase size of a div other one's size should decrease.

Comment: Your problem should be simpler to resolve as mine included child elements that were also resizable.

One of the elements contained a 5-way split into 20% so I will include the code for this in my answer as the whole solution I devised is rather complex. See below.

Answer (score 0):

I used [jQuery UI Resizable](http://jsfiddle.net/sebgc/q96nS/) and wrote custom function to handle the three resizable elements as well as their child elements.

As border and margins were used to create the white border, my solution had to cope with this too. It is a lot simpler to deal with just elements without borders. I also had to calculate for zero height elements and resize them to allow them to be visible while still retaining a zero value as their percentages were used in calculations.

You can dig into the full code if you need more detail but I have stripped down to [just the essentials you will need for your problem on this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sebgc/q96nS/).

The jQuery code as follows, using my original selectors - it will make sense in the example whihc includes necessary CSS and markup structure.

```
$('#act .weighting-category').resizable({
    minHeight: 0,       
    handles: 's',
    start: function(event, ui) {                        

        orig_height = $(this).height();

        actheight1 = $('#activity').height();

        basic_o_percent = $('#act .basic').height() / (actheight1-$(this).height());
        class_o_percent = $('#act .classifications').height() / (actheight1-$(this).height());
        related_o_percent = $('#act .related').height() / (actheight1-$(this).height());
        financial_o_percent = $('#act .financial').height() / (actheight1-$(this).height());
        performance_o_percent = $('#act .performance').height() / (actheight1-$(this).height());

    },
    resize: function(event, ui) {

        if($(this).hasClass('zero') && $(this).height() > 5){
            $(this).removeClass('zero');
        }
        if(!$(this).hasClass('zero')){

            if($(this).height() > orig_height  || orig_height < (actheight1)) {

                if($(this).attr('id')=='basic'){
                    $("#act .classifications").height( (actheight1  -$(this).height()) * class_o_percent);
                    $("#act .financial").height( (actheight1  -$(this).height()) * financial_o_percent);
                    $("#act .related").height( (actheight1  -$(this).height()) * related_o_percent);
                    $("#act .performance").height( (actheight1  -$(this).height()) * performance_o_percent);
                } else if( $(this).attr('id')=='classifications'){
                    $("#act .basic").height( (actheight1  -$(this).height()) * basic_o_percent);
                    $("#act .financial").height( (actheight1 -$(this).height()) * financial_o_percent);
                    $("#act .related").height( (actheight1  -$(this).height()) * related_o_percent);
                    $("#act .performance").height( (actheight1 -$(this).height()) * performance_o_percent);
                } else if( $(this).attr('id')=='financial'){
                    $("#act .classifications").height( (actheight1  -$(this).height()) * class_o_percent);
                    $("#act .basic").height( (actheight1 -$(this).height()) * basic_o_percent);
                    $("#act .related").height( (actheight1 -$(this).height()) * related_o_percent);
                    $("#act .performance").height( (actheight1 -$(this).height()) * performance_o_percent);
                } else if( $(this).attr('id')=='related'){
                    $("#act .classifications").height( (actheight1  -$(this).height()) * class_o_percent);
                    $("#act .financial").height( (actheight1 -$(this).height()) * financial_o_percent);
                    $("#act .basic").height( (actheight1  -$(this).height()) * basic_o_percent);
                    $("#act .performance").height( (actheight1 -$(this).height()) * performance_o_percent);
                } else if( $(this).attr('id')=='performance'){
                    $("#act .classifications").height( (actheight1  -$(this).height()) * class_o_percent);
                    $("#act .financial").height( (actheight1  -$(this).height()) * financial_o_percent);
                    $("#act .related").height( (actheight1 -$(this).height() ) * related_o_percent);
                    $("#act .basic").height( (actheight1  -$(this).height()) * basic_o_percent);
                }

            } else {


                targetheight = $(this).height();
                $('#act .weighting-category').not(this).each(function(){
                    $(this).height( (actheight2 - targetheight ) * 0.25);
                    if($(this).hasClass('zero') && $(this).height() > 0){
                        $(this).removeClass('zero');
                    }
                })                  
            }
        }




    },
    stop: function(event, ui) { 
        if($(this).height() == 0){
            $(this).addClass('zero');
        }
        totalheight = 0;
        $('#act > .weighting-category').each(function() {
            if(!$(this).hasClass('zero'))
            {
                totalheight += $(this).height();
            }
        });                                         

        actheight = 0;  
        $('#act .weighting-category').each(function(){              
            if(!$(this).hasClass('zero')){
                actheight += $(this).height();
            }
        })  

        actheight = 0;  
        $('#act .weighting-category').each(function(){              
            if(!$(this).hasClass('zero')){
                actheight += $(this).height();
            }
            if($(this).height() == 0 || $(this).hasClass('zero')){
                $(this).addClass('zero');

            }
        })  


        if($(this).height() >= actheight1)
        {
            $(this).animate({
                   height: (actheight1),
                 }, 500, function() {
            });
        }   


        $('#act .weighting-category').each(function(){
            if(!$(this).hasClass('zero')){
                thispercentage = $(this).height() / actheight;
                $(this).animate({
                       height: (maxheight * thispercentage),
                     }, 500, function() {
                });
            }               
        })                      

    }
});
```

Let me know how it goes.

[EDIT]: This does not work on IE 11 currently, however my original solution does. It likely just needs some troubleshooting for IE, but works on Chrome and Firefox latest versions.