# Set another string if id/class does not exist in the options of resizable widget (jquery-ui)

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-resizable

I implemented a customized widget (alsoResizeReverse) based on followed reference:
[jQuery UI Resizable alsoResize reverse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3369045/jquery-ui-resizable-alsoresize-reverse) (I use the accepted answer)

However, I am wondering is there any solution to set another id if the id that specified on alsoResizeReverse does not exist?

For instance, here is my current code:

```
$("#select").resizable({
        handles: "s",
        alsoResizeReverse: "#content-timesheet",
        minHeight: 74.25,
        maxHeight: 378
    });
```

If `"#content-timesheet"` does not exist, I would like to set another id. Therefore, more or less, the logic would be like this:

```
if($('#content-timesheet').length){
    alsoResizeReverse = "#content-timesheet";
}else{
    alsoResizeReverse = "#content-useditems";
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check the `length` property of the jQuery object in a ternary expression. Try this:

```
alsoResizeReverse: $('#content-timesheet').length ? '#content-timesheet' : '#content-useditems',
```

Ternary reference at MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator